# The trouble with a calculation of the set len

Tags: python-3.x

I can't resolve this problem:/ My code returned a bound method, not a len of the set. Help me with your advise, please!)

```
class PowerSet():

def __init__(self):
    self.powerset = set()

def size(self):
    return len(self.powerset)

def put(self, value):
    if value in self.powerset:
        raise KeyError
    else:
        return self.powerset.add(value)

a = PowerSet()
for i in range(10):
    a.put(i)
print(a.size)

# <bound method PowerSet.size of <__main__.PowerSet object at 0x7f7291042940>>

but

print(len(a.powerset))

# 10
```

Comment: `print(a.size())`, you forgot to call the method

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to `write len(a.size())` with brackets. Now you are asking to print the method, you are not callng it.